# Why does @unknown default (Swift 5) cause compile error?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I think I understand the logic behind @unknown default, and I apologize for screenshots instead of code, but it's the only way to see the error messages in context.

Converted a project to Swift 5. It runs, but gets this warning, which I understand:

[image]

So I let Xcode fix it for me, and got this:

[image]

I changed the order of the stub cases (this is a work in progress), which makes the compiler happy again:

[image]

Am I doing something I shouldn't, or is this weird compiler behavior?

Comment: Please don't use images for code pasting. Paste code directly.

Comment: Only did it so readers could see the error messages in context.

Comment: This is a known bug [SR-9920](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9920).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error in the middle image looks like a [bug in swift](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9920) and it could be solved by adding a semicolon at the end of the return statement.

In general the compiler is expecting `@unknown default` to be the last case. Check [@unknown documentation from apple](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md#unknown) where they explain why it must be used with the last case in a switch and more on the "unknown patterns" link in the following quote:

> @unknown may only be applied to default or a case consisting of the
>   single pattern _. Even in the latter case, **@unknown must be used with
>   the last case in a switch**. This restriction is discussed further in
>   the ["unknown patterns"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md#unknown-patterns) section under "Future directions".

Comment: How is the middle example not the last case?

Comment: Have you tried in your middle example to put a `;` at the end of `return` like: `return;`?

Comment: Late night, didn't think of that. Thank you, just tried it, it works. Still think it's an Xcode bug, since Swift makes a big deal about no semi-colons.

Comment: Yeah I guess is an xcode bug with the new swift 5 changes. I have added it as a statement in the answer to make sure it is addressed properly for future readers :)

Comment: "Still think it's an Xcode bug, since Swift makes a big deal about no semi-colons" That is not true. There are many other situations where you need a semicolon after `return` to prevent the compiler from thinking you're trying to return the next line.

Answer (score 0):

There are many situations where a bare `return` followed by another line of code causes Swift to think you’re trying to return that line of code. The situation is less confusing than it used to be, because now there is at least a warning to tell you about it (and the situation arises in a much smaller range of cases than it used to):

```
@IBAction func doDismiss(_ sender: Any) {
    return
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated:true)
}
```

That code looks legal, but it doesn’t compile, the result being a seemingly strange compile error:

```
Value of optional type 'Void?' must be unwrapped to a value of type ‘Void'
```

Fortunately, in this instance, the reason for the strangeness is now also revealed by a warning (usually):

```
Expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'
```

The solution has always been to add a semicolon after the `return`. Indeed, for those of us who have been using Swift since Swift 1, adding a semicolon after a bare `return` is practically a reflex action, even though it is usually no longer needed these days.

Your situation is basically a case of the same issue. The problem is that you don’t get the explanatory warning.

Comment: Nis there any documentation about that? Cause it looks like an xcode bug

Comment: The example you give is a slightly different case – that is a `return` followed by an *expression*, which is valid. OP's case is a `return` followed by a statement, which Swift should be able to treat as a bare return followed by a statement (rather than trying to parse the statement as an expression). This is a bug ([SR-9920](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9920)), [which has already been fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/22974) :)

Comment: @Hamish I changed the example to one that is a bit more compelling.

Comment: @matt That's still an expression following the return – consider other cases where a statement follows a return, e.g https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/b3014d64a8a9f820e29076ce0a211370, the compiler handles those properly.

Comment: @Hamish My only goal is to impress upon the OP that it is not unusual to have to write `return;` and that some of us just do it all the time.

Comment: @matt Fair enough – I just wanted to point out that there should be no parsing ambiguity in OP's case, it should compile without error or warning.

Comment: @Hamish I think they should _all_ compile without error or warning.